# Typically energy of black hole compared to a planet or star of the same mass

Tags: black-holes, mass-energy, estimation, large-hadron-collider

Is the typical energy of a black hole much lower than the typical energy of a same-mass planet or star? I guess the answer is yes, energy of black hole is much lower. Otherwise, physicists would strictly deny the possibility of LHC creating a black hole that can swallow the earth, instead of answering it with more complicated answers.

Comment: Nobody ever proposed the possibility of star massed black holes being generated by LHC. It was always about hypothetical microscopic black holes.

Comment: I was talking about microscopic black holes of course. The next question is if they have a reasonable chance to grow larger. A typically answer probably involves the rate of decay and the collision cross section (to absorb particles around it). My point there is that if the energy of a black hole is more than that of a planet (under whatever relevant constrain) then it is an energetically unfavorable process to create a blackhole that swallow the earth, so the reason why it would practically never happen, would be very simple.

Comment: Energy is $E=Mc^2$ whether for planet, star, or black hole.

Answer (score 4):

You ask about "the typical energy of a black hole". All the black holes that we know about have formed from the collapse of massive stars or the merger of stellar black holes, so they have masses from about 5 solar masses up to millions of solar masses for the supermassive black holes at centres of galaxies. The first problem is how can a planet or a star have the same mass as a stellar black hole without actually collapsing and forming a black hole itself ? I think that is only possible if the black hole is a [primordial black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) - which then begs the question of whether a primordial black hole (if such things exist) is a "typical" black hole.

Putting that issue to one side, how do you measure the energy of a black hole ? Well, one way is to determine its mass (from its gravitational effects) and then express this mass as an equivalent amount of energy using $E=mc^2$. But then the energy of a black hole is, by definition, the same as the energy of a planet or sun with the same mass.

Also, each proton in the LHC beam carries an energy of about $10^{-6}$ J, so any black hole that could possibly be created by the LHC will have a maximum mass/energy of only around twice this - obviously much, much smaller than a planet or a star.

In fact, physicists *have* denied that the LHC could create a black hole that can swallow the Earth. The answer to this question from [CERN FAQs](https://home.cern/resources/faqs/will-cern-generate-black-hole) says

> The LHC will not generate black holes in the cosmological sense. However, some theories suggest that the formation of tiny 'quantum' black holes may be possible. The observation of such an event would be thrilling in terms of our understanding of the Universe; and would be perfectly safe.

Comment: beside the point about density vs mass mentioned by Sebastian Riese
, I was talking about microscopic black hole. However, whether the microscopic black hole can grow bigger or not, partially depends on whether this whole process is energetically favorable or not. (Of course, there are other relevant factors like decay rate and chance of absorbing particles around it)

Comment: @BohanXu Then your question is badly phrased, since you talk about "the typical energy of a black hole", and a typical black hole, from what we know so far, is a stellar black hole. If you meant to ask about the hypothetical properties of microscopic black holes then you should have said so.

Comment: but the relevant property of microscopic black hole in this case (whether it can even in principle grow to planet size) is whether a planet/star massed blackhole is lower or higher in energy than the planet/star.... but I see your point of confusion now

Comment: “*The observation of such an event would be thrilling in terms of our understanding of the Universe; and would be perfectly safe.*” - People admitting their lack of understanding and in the same sentence calming “perfect safety” without any basis is laughable and sad at the same time.

Comment: @safesphere My understanding so far is two masses have lower potential energy when closer together. Large blackhole absorbing materials is a thermodynamically favorable process. What is preventing materials from becoming blackhole is kinetics, the large free energy barrier (coulomb and fermi energy barrier and entropic barrier of small black tend to evaporate faster than eating air molecules). One need to get to very high free energy barrier before the reaction of ever-increasing blackhole can happen spontaniously). Colliders might be catalyst (previously unfound low barrier pathway) though~

Comment: @BohanXu “*two masses have lower potential energy when closer together*” - There is no “potential energy” in General Relativity. “Potential energy” is a made up concept to make the Newtonian Gravity work. In reality, there is no gravitational “potential energy”. It cannot be observed or measured, it doesn’t exist. And it is neither needed nor used in General Relativity. Not even as a concept. Just forget it like phlogiston, luminous aether, and other made up concepts of the past. The energy of a black hole or planet is the same $E=Mc^2$

Answer (score 2):

As safesphere mentioned, the energy of a black hole with the mass of the Earth has the same energy as the Earth. I think it is also pertinent to add, in the context of the OP, that a black hole does not have to have at least as much mass/energy as the object it consumes and can in fact absorb objects with much greater energy than itself.

I am guessing you are asking about the feasibility of accidentally creating a man made black hole that is a threat to the existence of life on Earth.

The world's largest collider, the Large Hadron Collider, is capable of producing proton-proton collision energies of about 13 TEV which works out at about $\approx 2 \times 10^{-6} J$. (This is equivalent to roughly the kinetic energy of a mosquito flying at full speed.) The mass equivalence of the collision energy is simply $\approx 2 \times 10^{-6} J / c^2 \approx 2.2×10^{-33} Kg$.

[Wikipedia gives the evaporation time of black hole due to Bekenstein/Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) as approximately $$t \approx 3.3 \times 10^{-16} \ \left(\frac{Mass}{kg}\right)^3 s.$$ If we assume a LHC proton-proton collision produced a micro blackhole, then its theoretical evaporation time would be $$t \approx 3.3 \times 10^{-16} \ \left(\frac{2.2 \times 10^{-33} kg}{kg}\right)^3 s \approx 3.5 \times 10^{-114} s$$

Compare this time to the Planck time interval of $\approx 5.4×10^{−44} \ s$, ie the evaporation time is $\approx 10^{71}$ times smaller than the Planck time interval and there is no current technology that can come close to detecting such a brief event and I think it's reasonable to assume such a micro black hole would not have time to directly interact with other particles.

Some recent LHC experiments collided lead ions with collision energies of about 1 PEV, which is about 100 times the proton collision energies, but the evaporation time would still about $10^{69}$ times smaller than the Planck time interval. [The temperature of such a black hole would be about](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hbar+*c%5E3%2F%288*pi*G*Kg*K_B*2*10%5E%28-31%29%29):

$$T \approx 1.2 \times 10^{23} \left(\frac{kg}{Mass} \right) K \approx \ 1.2 \times 10^{23} \left(\frac {kg}{2 \times 10^{-31} kg}\right) K \approx 6 \times 10^{53} K$$

This is many orders of magnitude hotter than the temperature to instantly vaporise any metal or rock in the immediate vicinity and together with the radiation pressure of the evaporating micro black hole, it is unlikely that the black hole will be able to come into direct contact with any solid objects. This is effectively a form of [Leindenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect).

As the proposed initial size of a hypothetical artificial blackhole gets larger:

1. The temperature of the black hole drops and the vaporisation pressure of surrounding material that opposes the gravitational attraction drops, possibly to zero.
2. The Hawking radiation pressure drops significantly reducing another opposing force to the gravitational attraction.
3. The gravitational force increases.

Calculating the threshold minimum mass for a black hole to have the potential to increase in size and be a potential threat to the Earth is not trivial. It would require a detailed calculation of the radiation pressure due to Hawking radiation together with the pressure due to vaporisation of nearby materials. This is probably a calculation that CERN should carry out, if they have not already.

A major (possibly unjustified) assumption in this analysis, is the existence of Hawking radiation, which has yet to be observed.

However, for reassurance, we can note that cosmic rays from space regularly collide with molecules in the atmosphere. These collisions have many orders of magnitude more energy than the collisions produced in the LHC, without the formation of any black holes being observed.

P.S. For reference, there is a [handy calculator for some black hole parameters here](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator)

Comment: This sounds like the type of argument needed to address the blackhole consern. My question about the energy is related to whether becoming a black hole is a thermodynamically favorable process. For instance we can say a chuck of heavy radioactive element can to become iron if human can catalyzes such process. However a chuck of iron can essentially never become a chuck of carbon through catalysis. I wonder if becoming a blackhole is a thermodynamically favorable process which human can catalyzes in principle. I guess the answer is yes, but we cannot overcome the cascading reaction barrier yet.

Answer (score 0):

Agree Safesphere is correct. Energy is same, unless a quantum answer would change it in some way I have no knowledge of. As an aside, the gravity would be same as star or planet if equal mass, assuming measure taken at same distance away from the center of gravity. Light (photons) obviously get away from planets and stars gravitation. Deal is when near or inside the event horizon of an equal mass black hole the distance to the CoG is extremely short, e.g. only several kilometers. This can be visualized vis escape velocities;
earth thousands of mph
sun hundreds of millions mph
black hole 1.6 trillion mph
So, sadly you would need travel at speed of roughly one-fourth of a light-year per hour to escape the gravity of a black hole from inside the event horizon ~ a gigantic multiple of warp (light) speed.